# cmd agent job shows success but does nothing to the file

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell

I have a powershell script that launches an Excel macro to refresh pivot tables and data sources, it works fine when run manually or from cmd.

when run from Sql Agent job it succeeds without performing the Excel refresh.

I call the script with this command in the job step:

```
powershell -command "&'C:\rapport_declaratif\REFRESH_3.ps1'"
```

I tried calling it with powershell, with cmd, with xp_cmdshell but nothing seems to work.

I even called it differently, for exp when I call it with this command:

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\rapport_declaratif\REFRESH_3.ps1"
```

it runs forever.

I also googled and found that I have to create this folder:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\DeskTop
```

I did and it didn't solve the problem.

Below is my powershell script:

```
# Open Excel file
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$filePath = "C:\rapport_declaratif\Rapport_Declaratif.xlsm"
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$excel.Visible = $true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false 
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
#Write-Host "Running macro in excel to refresh data."#

$excel.Run("Refresh_ALL")

 Start-Sleep -s 30
 #Write-Host "data refreshed."#

$workbook.save()
   # Write-Host "saved."#
$workbook.close()
$excel.quit()
#Write-Host "Closed Excel"#
```

Comment: Does the PowerShell script work for you when you RDP to the SQL Server and run it from there? Or does it only work when run on your local machine? If it doesn't work on the SQL Server: (a) is Excel installed? (b) In a Run-as-Administrator PowerShell prompt have you run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`?

Comment: thanks for your reply, The powershell does not work when called from SQL Server and this is the issue. I don't run it on my local machine, I run it manually on the same server where SSMS is installed. Yes, excel is installed. no i didnt run the command set execution policy as unrestricted because I am not an administrator.

Comment: the execution policy on the machine is remotesigned